# Can I get my selected checkbox on a php form to say something else instead of "on"?

Tags: php, html, css, email, checkbox

I have found a PHP form that I have edited to suit my needs.

I have 12 check boxes. Each has a different option to select. They all email fine, but it says "on" next to the option in the email so I know who has selected what.

The only problem is that I'd rather have it say something else instead of "on"; is this possible?

Comment: Yes, add `value="something"`.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ yoohoo ^^^^^^^^

Comment: Comments are often neglected, *boohoo* then somebody comes along and pulls the rug right from under my feet lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- - C'mon Fred, I know you've been here long enough to know you probably should have posted it as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Mr.Llama hahaha yeah I know. Questions like these are often solved by a simple comment and shouldn't require an answer *per se*. Real problems with code however, and that require special attention on the other hand, require an answer be put in, because it just stands to be too long as a comment. Comments often solves things ;) I even +1'd the answer ;)

Comment: You're welcome @SaturnsEye Remember to mark Joe's answer as solved ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm sorry fred! much love for your answer also! <3

Comment: @SaturnsEye No problemo, enjoy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `value='whatever'` to the html.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food1" value="Beans">I would like beans
<input type="checkbox" name="food2" value="Chips">I would like chips
```

Comment: Thought I'd add my 2 cents (edit) and a +1 to boot ;)